# How to use speech to text in WP7 mango Application using inbuilt Mango voice feature programmatically

Tags: windows-phone-7

can we call inbuilt Windows phone mango voice feature programmatically as in we use Launcher and Choosers.

Is there a way I can use this feature for my Translator application where my application recognises the voices spoken in different languages and convert them to text in that particular language.

Do we have this feature in BING Translator service? if yes then how to use them?
also how to use the INbuilt voice command of my WP mango to build my application?

Answer (score 2):

> can we call inbuilt Windows phone mango voice feature progamatically as in we use Launcher and Choosers.

No. There is no speech API for Windows Phone as of right now. See [Microsoft TellMe](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Tellme/developers/default.aspx) for a upcoming API.

> Is there a way i can use this feature for my Translator application where my applictaion recogonises the voices spoken in different languages and convert them to text in that particular language.

No

> also how to use the INbuilt voice command of my WP mango to build my application?

You can't.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you have found an answer for this, but Wade Wegner from the azure team has a translating and OCR app built using the Bing translation services.  I have not tried it, but this seems like something you could use.