# Is there a speech recognition API for Windows Mobile?

Tags: windows-phone-7, mobile, speech-recognition

I'd like something equivalent to the [Android Speech Recognition Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html) where the OS will initiate the speech recording, pass the recorded speech to a hosted cloud service for processing and return an array of strings to the calling application.

I've had a look at some docs, but it is not clear if Microsoft support this (particularly where they provide the hosted cloud recogniser service).  Lots of docs refer to having to host your own server.

Comment: I actually meant Windows Phone (I thought that Mobile and Phone were just synynoms). Searching for Windows Phone throws up this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991774/how-to-use-speech-to-text-in-wp7-mango-application-using-inbuilt-mango-voice-fea

Comment: The [TellMe site](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Tellme/h/default.aspx) has a sign-up field for people interested in this. I'm interpreting this as "not yet but maybe".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything available for free - I'm relatively certain Microsoft deosn't provide anything (they didn't last we looked, which was about a year ago). [Chant](http://www.chant.net) has a variety of products.  We've used them successfully under WinMo 6.5.

Comment: @ctackle: Can you please confirm which chant product you used in WinMo.